# What are the downsides of installing Vuel.js with a script src link?

Tags: node.js, installation, webpack, vue.js

I am new to programming and I learned how to use laravel and vuejs (which now ship together in laravel 5.3). I'm only practicing Vuejs right now, and was wondering what is so wrong with installing Vuejs using a simple src link rather than going the complex way of installing with npm and node.js, which is another learning curve for me if I have to learn it down the road anyways. Thanks for answering, I just don't understand what could be wrong with a simpler minified src link for a Vue.js installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use standalone version of Vue.js via a simple minified src link, it will come with a template compiler. The Vue component templates will be compiled in the browser environment for every user, before rendering. Therefore it will be slower compared to the runtime build option.

If you create a project using npm and [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli), you will get the runtime build of Vue.js, which will also package the vue app into one single `app.js` file, thus minimizing network requests for your production app. Your users will have a much better experience.

If you are only getting started, you can go with the simple minified src link for now. Once you get used to the framework, you can start using vue-cli.